# How can I access an indexer by reference

Tags: c#, arrays, ref

I've created one class with an indexer.

```cs
public class IntArray
{
        protected int[] _thisArray = new int[20];

        // --------------- ARRAY --------------- //
        public int this[int index] { get => _thisArray[index]; }
}
```

Now I want to access the indexer by reference.
This is what I tried:

```cs
private void AccessWithReference()
{
        var intArray = new IntArray();
        SetByReference(ref intArray[0]);
}

private void SetByReference(ref int value) { value = 0; }
```

But I get an error. On the other hand, if I try to access directly the array `ref _thisArray[0]` everything is fine.
How can I access an indexer via ref?

Comment: An indexer is not required to be backed by anything you can access by reference (think computed values), which is why this will not work in general. With `public ref int this[int index] { get => ref _thisArray[index]; }` it will, though.

Comment: Yes. I confirm. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The Microsoft [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/using-indexers) says "An indexer value is not classified as a variable; therefore, you cannot pass an indexer value as a ref or out parameter."
You could use a temporary variable to make this work, like this:

```
private void AccessWithReference()
{
   IntArray intArray = new IntArray();
   int a = intArray[0];
   SetByReference(ref a);
}
```

An Indexer is a [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types) type already

Comment: Thanks for the answer. With your solution I would still need to add something into the stack and reassign it. I know that my example is using an int to make the situation simple, but in reality I have a very large struct with a long array. Maybe I could try something with ref returns.